# Accessing google custom search

Tags: google-custom-search

I am building a software that processes Google search results for a linguistic purpose. It makes multiple searches at a fast rate and opens links (10 to 100 links per search) at a fast rate to access the websites and extract texts.

I will be accessing Google through Custom Search API. The Custom Search terms of service appear to disallow this type of access because they say that the results cannot be modified or crawled; however, I have found an interpretation that allows some wiggle room for my software. Now my question: If I go ahead and build the software, will the Custom Search block the access?

Comment: maybe you should ask this kind of questions to the application support\authors

Comment: I have already asked Custom Search Help, but it takes weeks to get an answer from them if you get it at all. Also they are likely to give you an official, out-of-the-book answer. I want to hear from people who have experience with similar types of access.